# How to do an "in" query in entity framework?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

How can I do a select in linq to entities to select rows with keys from a list?  Something like this:

```
var orderKeys = new int[] { 1, 12, 306, 284, 50047};
var orders = (from order in context.Orders 
              where (order.Key in orderKeys) 
              select order).ToList();
Assert.AreEqual(orderKeys.Count, orders.Count);
```

I tried using the *Contains* method as mentioned in some of the answers but it does not work and throws this exception:

*LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Contains[Int32](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32], Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024201/how-to-use-the-in-operator-in-linq

Answer (score 50, accepted):

<del>Try this:</del>

```
var orderKeys = new int[] { 1, 12, 306, 284, 50047};
var orders = (from order in context.Orders 
              where orderKeys.Contains(order.Key);
              select order).ToList();
Assert.AreEqual(orderKeys.Count, orders.Count);
```

**Edit:** I have found some workarounds for this issue - please see [WHERE IN clause?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/095745fe-dcf0-4142-b684-b7e4a1ab59f0/):

> The Entity Framework does not
>   currently support collection-valued
>   parameters ('statusesToFind' in your
>   example). To work around this
>   restriction, you can manually
>   construct an expression given a
>   sequence of values using the following
>   utility method:

Comment: Perhaps you can look into these workarounds:  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/095745fe-dcf0-4142-b684-b7e4a1ab59f0/

Comment: if i do like this for string values then EF generated query without parameters, it just put string values into query

Comment: Looks like they have added support for "Contains". In the shared link, search for Zeeshan Hirani's post..

Answer (score 22):

I had the same problem and i solved like this

```
var orderKeys = new int[] { 1, 12, 306, 284, 50047};
var orders = (from order in context.Orders 
              where (orderKeys.Contains(order.Key)) 
              select order).ToList();
Assert.AreEqual(orderKeys.Count, orders.Count);
```

Comment: This answer is correct for entity framework 4, which was release with .net 4 - EF 4 was extended to perform a WHERE IN in this case - not all the way there yet, but closer

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately the EF can't translate the queries others have suggested. So while those queries would work in LINQ to Objects, they won't work in LINQ to Entities.

So the solution is a little more involved.

However I have a blog post on this exact topic [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2009/03/26/tip-8-writing-where-in-style-queries-using-linq-to-entities.aspx). Essentially the solution is to use a little expression tree magic to build an big OR expression.

Hope this helps

Alex