# How to use the IN operator in linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I'm querying a view and filtering the results with a column named status. I'd like to query it so I can search for rows with different status, by using the IN operator as I'd do in SQL.

As so:

SELECT * FROM VIEW WHERE Status in ('....', '.....')

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If your query expression uses the `Contains` method of an `IEnumerable` object, the parser will turn that into an `IN` expression using the values in the `IEnumerable`.

```
List<string> foo = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" };

var query = dataContext.View.Where(v => foo.Contains(v.Status));
```