# LINQ IN type query to get records based on result set of another query

Tags: c#, linq, odata

UserAuthorizations table has Company per User wise, and I want to get the list of Companies for the Users which are assigned as to them.

```
        // GET: odata/Companies/GetUserCompanies
        [EnableQuery]
        public IQueryable<UserAuthorization> GetUserCompanies()
        {
            List<int> userCompanyIds = db.UserAuthorizations.Where(u => u.Cwid == this.UserId).Select(s => s.CompanyId).ToList();
            return db.Companies.Where(m => m.Id.ToString().Contains(userCompanyIds));

        }
```

For above I am getting error like

```
Cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>' to 'string'
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want to return only companies, for which string representation of `Id` contains any value from the `userCompanyIds` list?

Comment: Yes you are right.
And I just tried it do ToString() because Id is an integer field and it does not have Contains option.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use the IN operator in linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024201/how-to-use-the-in-operator-in-linq)

Comment: @mjwills: I tried that approach just now, doest seem to work

List<string> userCompanyIds = db.UserAuthorizations.Where(u => u.Cwid == this.UserId).Select(s => s.CompanyId.ToString()).ToList();
            return db.Companies.Where(c => userCompanyIds.Contains(c.Id));

Gives an error cannot convert int to sting

Comment: Type of Company.Id is INTEGER, but the link you gave had an example of String, so thought of trying with that

Comment: `IQueryable<UserAuthorization>` Why is that your return type when your query is returning **Companies**? Read your exception - it tells you **exactly** what you did wrong.

Comment: @mjwills Thank you very much :) you pointed it perfectly. Thanks its working now with the provided Answer <3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try it

```
        public IQueryable<Company> GetUserCompanies()
        {
            List<int> userCompanyIds = db.UserAuthorizations.Where(u => u.Cwid == this.UserId).Select(s => s.CompanyId).ToList();
            return db.Companies.Where(m => userCompanyIds.Contains(m.Id));
        }
```

Comment: have added the screen shot in the question please check "https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTSL5.png"

Comment: you shoud return IQueryable<Company>,   "public IQueryable<Company> GetUserCompanies()" . i edited my answer

Comment: Sorry I didnt noticed "IQueryable<Company>" :)