# LINQ: Selecting products under a category, including sub-categories

Tags: linq, entity-framework

The code below searches for products matching a keyword `s` or being under a category matching the keyword `s`.

It is working but tedious, I am wondering if there is a shorter way to do this?

```
var products = context.Products.Where(x => 
                 x.Name.Contains(s) ||
                 x.Products_Categories.Any(pc => 
                     pc.Category.Name.Contains(s) || 
                     (pc.Category.Category1 != null && pc.Category.Category1.Name.Contains(s)) || 
                     (pc.Category.Category1 != null && pc.Category.Category1.Category1 != null && pc.Category.Category1.Category1.Name.Contains(s) || 
                     (pc.Category.Category1 != null && pc.Category.Category1.Category1 != null pc.Category.Category1.Category1.Category1 != null && &&pc.Category.Category1.Category1.Category1.Name.Contains(s))
               );
```

If it is not obvious:

`Products_Categories` is a many-to-many relationship, a `Product` can be in one or more `Category`.

`Category1` is the parent category of the `Category`.

Note that it is linked to a database so I cannot use functions like `IsUnderCategory()`.
I don't need Expression at the moment because this code is only used once.

Comment: Looks like you should create a View in database to get hierarchical data about categories (using Common Table Expression) and query using that View, not `Category` table itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no shortcut to recursive querying in linq, less so in linq that is backed by a SQL query provider. However, there is one upside of the statement being translated to SQL first *before* being executed: SQL has no notion of a null reference. So you remove all the `null` checks from your statement:

```
var products = context.Products.Where(x => 
                 x.Name.Contains(s) ||
                 x.Products_Categories.Any(pc => 
                     pc.Category.Name.Contains(s) || 
                     pc.Category.Category1.Name.Contains(s) || 
                     pc.Category.Category1.Category1.Name.Contains(s) || 
                     pc.Category.Category1.Category1.Category1.Name.Contains(s))
               );
```

It will be translated to a SQL statement with many outer joins. As you'll know SQL won't crash if you address a field of an outer joined table when it has no record.

The query will be... monstrous. And you have to assume a max depth of the hierarchy. The only way to improve that is creating a view in the database that returns all categories of a product by a [recursive SQL query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach using EF is to simply query iteratively all of the categories for subcategories using a while cycle.

When you're done, you have all of the IDs. The first time, the query plan is not yet done and it takes a little while but then it's very fast depending on how monstrous your database is.

Then you can just [query for all products that have any of a list of category IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13342905/169034) using the `Contains` method that gets translated to `WHERE FieldName IN (1,2,3)`

The advantage of this approach is that it is not dependent on how many levels of subcategories you have. It always works while the other alternative fails silently.