# Code First: Using sql IN keyword

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

How do I use the IN keyword under Code First?

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id IN (1,2,3);
```

Been looking around google and can't find anything unless the only way is raw sql.

Comment: what you are getting while executing the query

Comment: with the help of contains
`var val = tblName.Where(t => col1.Contains(paramName));`

Comment: Note sure what "code first" has to do with anything but the linq equivalent  `Where(x => ArrayOfValues.Contains(x.Id))` whill be translated to `WHERE IN` type sql

Comment: I haven't executed the query 'cause I don't know how I will write the query in where of c#.. but I'll try what @haim770 have commented

Comment: I've passed an array of int and receiving error `Unable to create a null constant value of type 'System.Int32[]'. Only entity types, enumeration types or primitive types are supported in this context.`

Comment: @juniordeveloper, Please update the question with what you have tried

Comment: @juniordeveloper, The last exception you mentioned is probably because you're creating the `int[]` inside the expression. Try to instantiate it before, just like in the other answer.

Comment: thanks, just solved the problem, I'm passing an array from js and it's being received as a string array.. will update my question now... how do I mark my question as already answered on the duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

This answer should help:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13342905/2892208

EF should decide how he render the script but I believe the .Contains method will fit here perfectly.