# How to filter by fields from navigation properties in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, navigation-properties

I have classes like:

```
public class ProductInCategory
{
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }
    public long ProductID { get; set; }
    public long ProductCategoryID { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductCategory ProductCategory { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public virtual ICollection<ProductInCategory> ProductsInCategories { get; set; }

    // and other fields and navigation properties not important for this example
}
```

And now I want to execute query which gets all products using Entity Framework with eager loading with specific ProductCategoryID's:

```
using (var db = new EntityDataModel())
{
    var node = db.Tree.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Guid == editedNode);
    List<long> descentantIds = db.Tree
                              .Where(x => x.AncestorID == node.AncestorID)
                              .Select(x => x.DescendantID).ToList();

    List<Product> products = db.Products
        .Include("Details")
        .Include("Prices")
        .Include("Prices.Currency")
        .Include("Prices.Seller")
        .Include("Translations")
        .Include("Translations.Language")
        .Include("ProductsInCategories")
        .Where(x => ... )) // how to filter by ProductsInCategories.ProductCategoryID (which in my case is descentantIds) ? 
        .ToList();
}
```

I think that I should to type in Where clause something similar to `.Where(x => descentantIds.Contains(x.ProductsInCategories.ProductCategoryID))`, but this won't work.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13342905/2549258) is similar solution, but I don't know how to apply it in my case.

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: what exactly do you want? that descentantIds contains ANY of the Ids in the ProductsInCategories? all? the other way around?

Comment: I want to achive equivalent of SQL `WHERE ProductsInCategories.ProductCategoryID IN (1, 2, 3 .. n) `, but I don't see how can I get by lambda expression value of ProductCategoryID in my navigation property ProductsInCategories. In my case Where statement is `IQueryable<Product>`

Comment: ProductionCategories is an ICollection of Products, which ProductCategoryID's do you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 .SelectMany(x => x.ProductsInCategories.Where(c => descentantIds.Contains(c.ProductCategoryID))).Select(c => c.Product).Distinct()
```

Answer (score 0):

Although @mariovalens gave working solution which solved my issue I found another one. I'm pasting both of them. It might be helpful for others ;)

Note that for proper eager loading insert .Include() methods after filtering methods like SelectMany(), Select(), Where() etc. Inputing .Include() before those methods will return null values in navigation properties.

```
using (var db = new EntityDataModel())
{
    var node = db.Tree.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Guid == editedNode);
    List<long> descentantIds = db.Tree
               .Where(x => x.AncestorID == node.AncestorID)
               .Select(x => x.DescendantID)
               .ToList();

    List<Product> method1 = db.Products
        .SelectMany(x => x.ProductsInCategories.Where(c => descentantIds.Contains(c.ProductCategoryID))).Select(c => c.Product).Distinct()
        .Include(c => c.Assets.Select(c1 => c1.Translations.Select(c2 => c2.Language)))
        .Include(c => c.Tags.Select(c1 => c1.Translations.Select(c2 => c2.Language)))
        .Include(c => c.Details)
        .Include(c => c.Prices.Select(c1 => c1.Currency))
        .Include(c => c.Prices.Select(c1 => c1.Seller))
        .Include(c => c.Translations.Select(c1 => c1.Language))
        .Include(c => c.ProductsInCategories)
        .ToList();

    var method2 = (from product in db.Products
                 join productsInCategories in db.ProductsInCategories
                 on product.ID equals productsInCategories.ProductID
                 join productsCategories in db.ProductsCategories
                 on productsInCategories.ProductCategoryID equals productsCategories.ID
                 where descentantIds.Contains(productsInCategories.ProductCategoryID)
                 select product)
                 .Include(c => c.Assets.Select(c1 => c1.Translations.Select(c2 => c2.Language)))
                 .Include(c => c.Tags.Select(c1 => c1.Translations.Select(c2 => c2.Language)))
                 .Include(c => c.Details)
                 .Include(c => c.Prices.Select(c1 => c1.Currency))
                 .Include(c => c.Prices.Select(c1 => c1.Seller))
                 .Include(c => c.Translations.Select(c1 => c1.Language))
                 .Include(c => c.ProductsInCategories);

    var result = method2.ToList<Product>();
}
```