# Filter a list by the elements from another list. Error: Unable to create a constant value of type 'xyz'

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to filter a list by the elements from another list, using the following code:

```
public JsonResult GetEquipamentosByFiliaisInstalacao(List<EmpresaFocusDTO> filiais)
{
    var instalacoesFiltradasPorFiliais = _db.Instalacao
    .Where(i => filiais.Any(s => s.Id == i.IdFilialFocus))
    .ToList()
```

I'm getting the following error on the linq line:

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'MasterCoin.DTO.Focus.EmpresaFocusDTO'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

What do I have to do?

---

Here is the classes asked by @er-shoaib :

```
public class EmpresaFocusDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Sigla { get; set; }
}

public partial class Instalacao
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Serie { get; set; }
    public int Distancia { get; set; }
    public int Deslocamento { get; set; }
    public int IdEquipamentoFocus { get; set; }
    public int IdClienteFocus { get; set; }
    public bool Ativo { get; set; }
    public string NomeEquipamentoFocus { get; set; }
    public string NomeClienteFocus { get; set; }
    public int IdFilialFocus { get; set; }
    public int IdGrupoFocus { get; set; }
    public string NomeFilialFocus { get; set; }
    public string NomeGrupoFocus { get; set; }
    public int IdRepresentanteFocus { get; set; }
    public string NomeRepresentanteFocus { get; set; }
    public string Uf { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you using LINQ to SQL, Entity Framework or Entity Framework Core?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework - attribute IN Clause usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13342817/entity-framework-attribute-in-clause-usage)

Comment: @er-shoaib I have edited the questions to add the classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says:

> Only primitive types are allowed

You need to create a collection of just id columns and then use it in your linq query. Ef is not able to cater with your custom type collection.

Try this:

```
var ids = filiais.Select(s => s.Id).ToList();
var instalacoesFiltradasPorFiliais = _db.Instalacao
    .Where(i => ids .Any(s => s == i.IdFilialFocus))
    .ToList()
```

Comment: What is the benefit of using `Any` vs `Contains`?

Comment: @mjwills - staying close to the original question is a benefit.

Comment: not sure but i guess both could be used they will be translated to same sql