# Multiple records using Find method in Entity Framework by passing list of primary keys

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a `Contact` table in SQL Server, I mapped the table using Entity Framework in my C# console application:

```
EmployeeId  FirstName   LastName
--------------------------------
1           Ram         Kumar
2           Mohan       Raj
3           Aravind     Swaamy
4           Ajay        Kumar
5           Ram         Raj
```

I need to fetch the records of 1, 3, 5 (`EmployeeId`)

Currently I'm doing in the following way

```
List<Employees> emp = new List<Employees>();

var emp1 = dbContext.Employee.Find(1);
var emp3 = dbContext.Employee.Find(3);
var emp5 = dbContext.Employee.Find(5);

emp.Add(emp1);
emp.Add(emp3);
emp.Add(emp5);
```

Kindly assist me how to get list of records using `Find` method by passing a list of primary key values.

Some people thinking the question is duplicate of [How to do an "in" query in entity framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137921/how-to-do-an-in-query-in-entity-framework). No it's absolutely wrong. My question is how to fetch multiple records using `Find` extension method. Because `IN` operation perform slower than the `Find` operation.

Comment: @CodeCaster: IN operation perform slower than .find() did you know this?

Comment: You can't do that..If you only load a few object use a IN statement. If you load hundred/thousands of object the best way to do it is using a join. Unfortunately you can't join a DbSet with an in memory table so you'll have to write a stored proc (and of course you'll lose object tracking)

Comment: I think this is a valid question... Using find will enable you to leverage the EF cache... So it's advantageous over a IN/Contains call... Of course, assuming the parameters are PKs for your entity. It seems very reasonable that EF should support a way to lookup and cache multiple entities by PK in a single database call.

Answer (score 10):

> My question is how to fetch multiple records using FIND extension method.

You can't; `Find()` finds one record, which is not what you want.

> Because IN operation perform slower than the FIND operation.

No, it's not. Your current code does this:

```
SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE EmployeeId = 1
SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE EmployeeId = 3
SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE EmployeeId = 5
```

In three database roundtrips. That is by definition slower than this:

```
SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE EmployeeId IN (1, 3, 5)
```

> If the data count is large, the WHERE clause perform very slow than FIND. This is fact.

No, it's not. `Find()` is not SQL. It translates to `WHERE PK_COL=value` for any amount of primary key columns and values for one record. The reason `Find()` has a `params` parameter is because of compound primary keys.

So, the [duplicate I linked to before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137921/how-to-do-an-in-query-in-entity-framework) **does** answer your question and does exactly what you want:

```
var primaryKeys = new int[] { 1, 3, 5 };

var employees = dbContext.Employee.Where(e => primaryKeys.Contains(e.EmployeeId));
```

Which translates to the `WHERE ... IN` shown above.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please think in different way without WHERE and Contains

Comment: No, **you** need to go and think in a different way. You're thinking WHERE is slow, but it's not.

Comment: Don't forget that there is a limit in the number of elements in "IN"

Comment: @GeorgeVovos: I can't able to understand "Don't forget that there is a limit in the number of elements in 'IN'." Could you please brief me...

Comment: @B.Balamanigandan http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069415/limit-on-the-where-col-in-condition